# boost Rtree of points, which spatial query method (covered_by, intersects and within) is more efficient to search points covered by a bouding box?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, boost-geometry, r-tree

I am a c++ beginner and am using the Rtree algorithm implemented in boost::geometry::index library [`boost::geometry::index library (bgi)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes.html) . I want to do a spatial query to get all the points fall in a given bounding box. From my understading on the introduction of [`Queries`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/spatial_indexes/queries.html), I found `bgi::covered_by`,`bgi::intersects`, and `bgi::within` all meet my requirment. I probably need to do up to billions of query, I am wondering is there any efficiency difference between these 3 methods?

I tried to look at the details in the code to find how they are implemented, but it seems it is to advanced for me to understand.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question! ;-) And you should provide some code that you have tried, even if it does not build, to see exactly what you are trying to achieve. That way, some people could help, by pointing out your misunderstandings.

Comment: As @kebs said: try it out and benchmark the different options. Performance may also depend a lot on your data.

Comment: Thanks to both for the comments. But I think the answer lies in the fundament of how these query algorithms are implemented in the library, I wanted to know what and why (if exist) there is a difference between them. This however, I cannot get any clue because I am not able to understand the source code.

Comment: "I want to do a spatial query to get all the points fall in a given bounding box" - then you don't need the `intersects` query, because it makes sense for larger geometric objects only (like segments, boxes etc.)